# ExoPlayer don't start video on android

Tags: java, android, video, mp4, exoplayer

this is my code:

```
String url = "https://cdn1.kinogo.by/movies/bf9ee1517cb600e6dec74fac3ae780b5d7a558ab/06d811719e510e57736df5120155f92e:2018083116/240.mp4";

//redirected here https://polonium.cdn1.kinogo.by/movies/bf9ee1517cb600e6dec74fac3ae780b5d7a558ab/06d811719e510e57736df5120155f92e:2018083116/240.mp4

exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, new DefaultTrackSelector());
exoView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this,"myApp"));
ExtractorMediaSource extractorMediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url),null,null);
exoPlayer.prepare(extractorMediaSource);
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Tell me what could be the problem? If you use a different URL,

for example this: http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4

then everything works fine. What can be the solution for this URL?

If possible, please give me some links or code snippets, or I did not find anything.

Comment: this link (String url = ...) works on MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

In exoplayer, you need to enable the URL redirect.